# The file appname couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting build error, using Xcode 7.3.1, deployment target 7.0.

Please help me solve this issue.

```
ProcessProductPackaging  /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-epjwtzplzmwqyrfttrtkajxjpgcx/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.build/appname.app.xcent
    cd /Users/user1/Downloads/appname-universal
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-productPackagingUtility /Users/user1/Downloads/appname-universal/appname -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-epjwtzplzmwqyrfttrtkajxjpgcx/Build/Intermediates/appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.build/appname.app.xcent

error: The file appname couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

Comment: Do you add your file to Copy Bundle Resources?

Comment: Sanity check.... Does the file actually exist at the location?  If not, was this the **first** reported error in the build?

Comment: Files were added in in Copy Bundle Resources.